# Pyspaprk counting number of occurrences fitting a condition

Tags: pyspark, group-by, count, conditional-statements

In pyspark I have data in df per country and I want to count number of occurrences  when value equals  less than 100. And also number  of occurrences  when value  equals  less than 1000.

```
Country  value 
Us         10
Us         150
Us         102
Us         15000
Ru         13
Ru         175
Ru         122
Ind        14000
Ind        2000
Ind        780
Ind        900
Ind        55
```

Us has 1 occurence below  100. And 3 below  1000.
Ru has 1 below  100 and 3 below 1000
Etc..

How do I get this information  ? Is there a way to group  by country  and count occurrences met by a condition? And if so is it possible  to differ each condition. Like once by 100 and the other by 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window to partition by the `Country` and you can conditionally sum the counts.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('Country')

df.withColumn('100', sum(when(col('value') <= 100, 1)).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('1000', sum(when(col('value') <= 1000, 1)).over(w)) \
  .show()

+-------+-----+---+----+
|Country|value|100|1000|
+-------+-----+---+----+
|     Ru|   13|  1|   3|
|     Ru|  175|  1|   3|
|     Ru|  122|  1|   3|
|     Us|   10|  1|   3|
|     Us|  150|  1|   3|
|     Us|  102|  1|   3|
|     Us|15000|  1|   3|
|    Ind|14000|  1|   3|
|    Ind| 2000|  1|   3|
|    Ind|  780|  1|   3|
|    Ind|  900|  1|   3|
|    Ind|   55|  1|   3|
+-------+-----+---+----+
```

Comment: Hey very great and concice answer. Is there a way to do two conditions inside? it deosnt work for me. Like for example two columns to satisfy this condtion <100

Comment: `when((col('value') <= 100) & (one more condition), 1)`

Comment: I tried it of course. It gives me error.  Because  its inside a sum it tells me to wrap it or whatever

Comment: Works . How do you retriev the results at the end? how can iget per group just the number as  a number.?  I need any random row per group would give me the result but how do i practically do it?